# how can I make the celery task call back to flask when it is finished

Tags: python, celery

When integrating celery with a Flask app, i have a longtime task that needs to callback to flask when the task is finished

```
@celery_app.task(bind=True)
def doSth(self):
    rv = long_time_job()
    return rv

@task_success.connect(sender=doSth)
def on_add_success(sender, result, **kwargs):
    #tell flask that a task has been done
    pass
```

but i have no idea

Answer (score 1):

A celery task is run indepently from the Flask server through a worker, they are two different process communicated with a message broker (rabbitmq?). So, when the task ends, that callback function should be done having the former in mind, two different process.

Here I give you two solutions:

- Webhook: define an HTTP URL in the Flask server and do a GET with the task id at the end of the task so Flask knows.
- Database: use a thread-safe database and keep the status of the task there. Flask will never know the task is ended until it queries the database (i.e. polling), not realtime but still an option.

Comment: webhook maybe a best try